# Is Telegram logo available as a character in Unicode?

Tags: unicode, telegram-bot

I have developed a [Telegram](https://telegram.org/) bot. I want to send a text message with the bot.

In that message I want to insert [Telegram](https://telegram.org/) logo besides my Telegram address but in a text message you cannot insert both image and text like in an html page.
I am constrained to use Unicode characters in my message. There are characters for phone, email, etc. in Unicode character set but I didn't find a character for [Telegram](https://telegram.org/) logo. Is there such a character in Unicode or not?

The best possible character I found is [Black Rightwards Arrowhead](https://unicode-table.com/en/27A4/) with code U+27A4.

[image: What I could do vs. what I want to do]

Answer (score 0):

No any organization icon added to Unicode for now, even is Google or Facebook.

If you see web pages use those icon, most of them use Font Awesome, likes [fa-telegram](http://fontawesome.io/icon/telegram/), [fa-stack-overflow](http://fontawesome.io/icon/stack-overflow/) icon.

Comment: I think that's not a font actually. That's a set of icons. Am I right?

Comment: @OmidSadeghi Sure, it can be use only if you are web server owner

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you might consider a generic unicode symbol for messages, like "Speech balloon", U+1f4ac: .